# What's the harm of dying in Spore?

Tags: spore

**Is there any harm, or any other effect from dying in Spore**, in cell or creature phase?

It seems to me that the only consequence is that you get a death mark to your evolution history. However you still get to keep the collected evolution discoveries (new parts), all the collected DNA points.

I mean sure, the game is partly based on the story you are creating for your species, and it's sad to see your little critter bite the dust. However, it doesn't seem like there's much point in trying to avoid risk. One could even go as far as to consider using death as a teleport back to home nest in creature phase (the poor little creature just wandered too far, oh the tragedy...) Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main problem is the loss of any companions in creature phase, which can take time to regain; especially if you're taking other species with you.

Comment: Not quite -- the achievement is just for completing the phase on hard.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Darn my fuzzy half-memory. Edited, thanks.

Comment: Good point! However, is it also the only problem, or are there other significant effects?

Answer (score 7):

In all my playthroughs, I've never found a penalty to dying in the early stages.

However, I am emotional attached to a creature, so don't often die.

There are in-game awards/achievements, so it could be possible there is one for a certain number of deaths or playing through the game with no deaths, but I have never gotten one nor am very into these awards, so I can't tell you about them.

Comment: I wonder if there's some other effect than direct harm. Could it somehow affect how the world is populated with other creatures?

Answer (score 4):

There are only two death based achievements in spore, and only one of them is in the creature stage:

> **General Custer:** Lead 30 posse members
>   to their deaths.

The other is part of the tribal stage:

> **Watchful Parent:** Complete the tribal
>   stage without the death of a tribe
>   member

Other than those, death is pretty meaningless. You get a mark on your evolutionary history, and a small, skippable, cutscene, and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 achievements related to you (or your allies) dying, and Raven Dreamer said 2 of them.

He forgot to mention

> **Survivor:** Finish the Creature Stage without dying.

as well as

> **Can't Win for Losing:** Die at least once in every stage in spore.

:)

Answer (score 2):

There can be a downside for dieing in creature stage--- it can trigger a migration event.

A migration can range from a minor inconvenience for a herbie or omni, to a significant hazard to continuing the game for a carnie. Carnies can only get food from dead creatures, and if you died and lost all your pack mates at the same time, you may not have sufficent resources to attack any of the surviving species to make dinner. Unless you built your creature to be able to sing well (not likely with carni mouths), dance, pose, and charm well (possible, but not likely as they don't aid in killing), you will now be on a "beat the clock" challenge. You will need to reach the new nest before you starve to death to reset your spawn point to be with your tribe. The old nest is only good for respawning. It doesn't have any recruitable pack mates at it.

This situation is why I no longer wipe out the early species. So I have snacks for these inconveniences--- as well as snacks for when I'm exploring but can't find anything suitable for dinner among the new species and my current carnie capabilities.